# lightning web components- save form data to the controller

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

```
<template>
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Gl__c">
<lightning-input-field field-name="RGl__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
                                    </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="BGl__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
                                        </lightning-input-field>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
<footer class="slds-modal__footer">
             <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick={closeModal}>Cancel</button>

             <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick={saveModal}>Save</button>
          </footer>
    <!-- modal code is here -->
  </template>
```

How to get the data from fields in the form into the apex controller so I can add data to the other fields and insert the record. I have many fields which I couldn't copy paste here, **Is there a way that I can save all the fields of the object in a list and pass that list to the apex controller in Lightning Web components?**

event.detail.RGl__c to get the value from the field but if I have many fields, is there a way to code efficiently?

Updated code:
lwc.js

```
  import { LightningElement, track, api} from 'lwc';
   import GL_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Gl__c';

 import saveGlRecord from '@salesforce/apex/GlController.saveGlRecord';



export default class CreateGlModel extends LightningElement {
@track showModal=true; 
flag = false;
@api reqId; 
@api bShowModal = this.showModal;
@track glRecord = {};
saveModal(){
    this.showModal = false;

    saveGlRecord({id: this.reqId},{gl: { ...this.glRecord, sobjectType: GL_OBJECT.objectApiName } })
          .then(result => { this.f = result })
          .catch(error => { this.error = error })
}
handleFieldChange(e) {
    this.glRecord[e.currentTarget.fieldName] = e.target.value;
}
 }
```

Apex Controller:

```
    public static Boolean saveGlRecord(String id, Gl__C gl){
     Boolean flag = false;
     System.debug('gl'+ gl);
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Added based on omments (for creating record):**

1. There is no need of Apex to create record as you have standard [createRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_salesforce_write). However, I have provided sample code for both below.
2. Get the record values from `onload` event of record-edit-form and create a record structure from that data. Filter the fields based on what fields are used in form.
3. While processing through Apex, you need `sobjectType`.

Sample:

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Contact">
        <lightning-messages>
        </lightning-messages>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="AccountId" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="FirstName" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="LastName" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Email" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small"
                          variant="brand"
                          name="save"
                          label="Save from createRecord"
                          onclick={saveForm}>
        </lightning-button>
        <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small"
                          variant="brand"
                          name="saveApex"
                          label="Save from Apex"
                          onclick={upsertCon}>
        </lightning-button>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { createRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import upsertContact from '@salesforce/apex/poc.upsertContact';
import CONTACT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Contact';

export default class Poc extends LightningElement {
    @track contactRecord = {};

    handleFieldChange(e) {
        this.contactRecord[e.currentTarget.fieldName] = e.target.value;
    }

    upsertCon() {
        upsertContact({ con: { ...this.contactRecord, sobjectType: CONTACT_OBJECT.objectApiName } })
            .then((contact) => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Contact upserted from apex => ' + contact.Id,
                        variant: 'success'
                    })
                );
            })
            .catch((err) => console.error(err));
    }

    saveForm() {
        // if(this.validated())
        console.log('Contact for save => ', JSON.stringify(this.contactRecord));
        createRecord({ apiName: CONTACT_OBJECT.objectApiName, fields: this.contactRecord })
            .then(contact => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Contact created from saveForm => ' + contact.id,
                        variant: 'success'
                    })
                );
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error creating record',
                        message: error.body.message,
                        variant: 'error'
                    })
                );
            });
    }
}
```

Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Contact upsertContact(Contact con) {
    System.debug('con => '+con);
    upsert con;
    return con;
}
```

---

**For updating record:**

1. There is no need of Apex as you have standard [updateRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_update_record). However, if you have some other logic which has to be in Apex only, then you can pass the record to Apex. Given example of both in below POC.
2. Get the record values from `onload` event of record-edit-form and create a record structure from that data. Filter the fields based on what fields are used in form.
3. While processing through Apex, you need `sobjectType`.

Below is the example:

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form record-id="00328000008ZUIdAAO"
                                onload={handleLoad}
                                object-api-name="Contact">
        <lightning-messages>
        </lightning-messages>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="AccountId" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="FirstName" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="LastName" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Email" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small"
                          variant="brand"
                          name="save"
                          label="Save from updateRecord"
                          onclick={saveForm}>
        </lightning-button>
        <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small"
                          variant="brand"
                          name="saveApex"
                          label="Save from Apex"
                          onclick={updateCon}>
        </lightning-button>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import updateContact from '@salesforce/apex/poc.updateContact';

export default class Poc extends LightningElement {
    @track contactRecord = {};

    updateCon() {
        updateContact({ con: { ...this.contactRecord, sobjectType: 'Contact' } })
            .then(() => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Contact updated',
                        variant: 'success'
                    })
                );
            })
            .catch((err) => console.error(err));
    }

    handleLoad(event) {
        if (!this.loadedForm) {
            let fields = Object.values(event.detail.records)[0].fields;
            const recordId = Object.keys(event.detail.records)[0];
            this.contactRecord = {
                Id: recordId,
                ...Object.keys(fields)
                    .filter((field) => !!this.template.querySelector(`[field-name=${field}]`))
                    .reduce((total, field) => {
                        total[field] = fields[field].value;
                        return total;
                    }, {})
            };
            this.loadedForm = true;
        }
    }
    handleFieldChange(e) {
        this.contactRecord[e.currentTarget.fieldName] = e.target.value;
    }
    saveForm() {
        // if(this.validated())
        console.log('Contact for save => ', JSON.stringify(this.contactRecord));
        updateRecord({ fields: this.contactRecord })
            .then(() => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Contact updated',
                        variant: 'success'
                    })
                );
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error creating record',
                        message: error.body.message,
                        variant: 'error'
                    })
                );
            });
    }
}
```

Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Contact updateContact(Contact con) {
    update con;
    return con;
}
```

**NOTE:**

If you also need to use `lightning-input` in `record-edit-form`, you can refer to this example: [Building an efficient LWC form without record-edit-form](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273973/building-an-efficient-lwc-form-without-record-edit-form)

**Correction from question:**

The problem is in :

```
saveGlRecord({id: this.reqId},{gl: { ...this.glRecord, sobjectType: GL_OBJECT.objectApiName } })
```

This will not work as all the parameters should be passed in single object:

```
saveGlRecord({
        id: this.reqId, 
        gl: { ...this.glRecord, sobjectType: GL_OBJECT.objectApiName } 
    })
```

Comment: your example is awesome, I have learnt new things but it is for updating the record, I am looking for inserting a new record. I have updated code in the post at the bottom but I am still stuck to send the contactRecord to apex

Comment: updated answer..

Comment: When I am printing the variable in the apex controller, it is still null, in your code import { createRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi'; but it doesn't call apex controller :(. Still not working for me

Comment: that is standard one

Comment: added upsertContact in answer. it should definitely work, I just checked it in my org

Comment: I need to add more field values from a different object to this object before saving in the apex controller. I want to send it as parameters

Comment: I am still getting null in the apex controller I will update my code exactly I wrote

Comment: if you use exact code that I provided, it should work. added debug apex - that will show you the contact record before upsert

Comment: can you see my code and correct me where I went wrong I did call exactly the way  you called in upsert, stilll in apex controller it is still null

Comment: you dont have `onchange` in `lightning-input-field` - so basically record is not getting updated and so its null

Comment: I forgot to update here but in the code I have onchange={handleFieldChange} updated the post. still null :(

Comment: added at end of answer

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. simple mistake took so long to complete. Thanks once again

Answer (score -1):

Apex:-

public without sharing class subscribe {
@AuraEnabled
public static void createRecord (string email){
if(email!=null){
insert new Subscriber__c(email__c = email);
}
}
}

HTML:-

```
<lightning-card >
    <h2> Subscribe Blogs</h2>
    <lightning-input  type="email" name="txtFname" onchange={handleChange} ></lightning-input>
  <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Subscribe" title="Submit" onclick={saveRecord} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
</lightning-card>
```

JS:-

import { LightningElement , api ,track} from 'lwc';
import email_field from '@salesforce/schema/Subscriber__c.Email__c'
import saveRegRecord from '@salesforce/apex/subscribe.createRecord';

export default class Subscribe extends LightningElement {
@track regRecord = {
fName : email_field
};

```
email;

handleChange(event) {
    this.email = event.target.value;            
}

saveRecord(event)
{
    saveRegRecord({email : this.email})

    .then(result => {
        // Clear the user enter values
        console.log(this.regRecord)
        this.conrec = {};            
        window.console.log('result ===> '+result);
        alert('You have Succesfully Subscribed to us');
    })
    .catch(error => { this.error = error.message;
        console.log('error==>'+this.error);
        alert('record not inserted');
    });
```

}
}

Comment: I've downvoted this because it is a _code dump_. The explanation of _what_ mistakes OP made, _how_ this solution works, and _why_ it works are every bit as important as the solution itself.