# how do i create dependent picklist in lighning web component(LWC) when creating a record[SOLVED]

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

JS:

```js
    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
            recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', 
            fieldApiName : COUNTRY_FIELD})  picklistValuescon;
    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
            recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', 
            fieldApiName : CITY_FIELD})  picklistValuescity;
```

HTML:

```html
    <template if:true={picklistValuescon.data}>
                        <lightning-combobox
                            style="width: 200px;"
                            value={picklistValuescon.data.values}
                            options={picklistValuescon.data.values}
                            placeholder="Select an Option"
                            label="Country"
                            onchange={handlecountryChange}
                        ></lightning-combobox>
                        <lightning-combobox
                            style="width: 200px;"
                            value={picklistValuescity.data.values}
                            options={picklistValuescity.data.values}
                            placeholder="Select an Option"
                            label="City"
                            onchange={handlecityChange}
                        ></lightning-combobox>
                    </template>
```

Comment: Pls use `{}` to format code after pasting and before pasting pls indent the code properly.

Comment: ok please help me out to make dependent picklist in LWC

Comment: Given answer. +1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Option 1: (RECOMMENDED) When both the controlling and dependent picklist fields are present in `record-edit-form`, dependent picklist options are updated automatically when you select an option in controlling field**

```html
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Account">
        <lightning-messages>
        </lightning-messages>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Name">
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="UpsellOpportunity__c">
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="SLA__c">
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small"
                          variant="brand"
                          type="submit"
                          name="update"
                          label="Update">
        </lightning-button>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
```

Here `SLA__c` is dependent on `UpsellOpportunity__c`.

---

**Option-2: Get the picklist values from `getPicklistValues` and implement custom logic using `combobox`**

You will get the data about `controllerValues` and `validFor` in dependent picklist field. You can use the change handler of controlling field to set the options for dependent field. Below is the example:

HTML:

```html
    <template>
        <lightning-combobox name="Upsell"
                            label="Upsell"
                            placeholder="Select Upsell"
                            options={upsellOptions}
                            onchange={handleUpsellChange}>
        </lightning-combobox>
        <lightning-combobox name="Sla"
                            label="Sla"
                            placeholder="Select Sla"
                            options={slaOptions}>
        </lightning-combobox>
    </template>
```

JS:

```js
    import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
    import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
    import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';
    import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
    import SLA_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.SLA__c';
    import UPSELL_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.UpsellOpportunity__c';
    
    export default class Poc extends LightningElement {
        @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
        accountInfo;
    
        @track slaOptions;
        @track upsellOptions;
    
        @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$accountInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: SLA_FIELD })
        slaFieldInfo({ data, error }) {
            if (data) this.slaFieldData = data;
        }
    
        @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$accountInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: UPSELL_FIELD })
        upsellFieldInfo({ data, error }) {
            if (data) this.upsellOptions = data.values;
        }
    
        handleUpsellChange(event) {
            let key = this.slaFieldData.controllerValues[event.target.value];
            this.slaOptions = this.slaFieldData.values.filter(opt => opt.validFor.includes(key));
        }
    }
```

Comment: yeah thanks, I have used option 1 it is working but it is now saved in my field in the object when I will something in this

Comment: can you pls clarify what you commented above?

Comment: I have used option 1 and it is working but when I fill these picklist value and click on save button it is not saved in the object

Comment: you need to use button type="submit" as shown here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation

Comment: modified in answer with button

Comment: yeah but i do not want use standard button

Comment: Its not clear what do you want to do. However you can refer to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274178/lightning-web-components-save-form-data-to-the-controller/274189#274189

Comment: @areeb, for marking answer as solved, you need to click on tick mark on left side of answer. You should not write in question title

Comment: @salesforce-sas is there another option using lightning:select? currently all my other dropdown list uses lightning:select

Comment: `Select` is available in Aura but not in LWC

Comment: Might be worth adding that when you have dependent fields across multiple sections on a LWC form (and therefore, multiple edit forms), you can simply add the controlling fields to other sections but add the 'hide' class to them.